# ExtJS grid and cell merging

Tags: extjs

does anybody know if it's possible to have the cell merging feature in the ExtJs grids?

then is the ExtJs grid working exactly in the same way in all browser and in the Android phones browser as well?

Thanks!

Comment: May be this link will help you ... http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246099-GridPanel-rowSpan-and-colSpan&s=fef07f932707c90d0cd923a47ae5b02b ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CY5s1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box a Grid(View) will never support this and negative margins won't work on all browsers. The more I think about it I must say no, you can't do this a save way.
The only possible solution is a custom rendered Table with a custom storebind. But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: so no way to have rowspan or colspan set to anything different than 1 in the Extjs Grid, this is what we are saying!? strange thinking that HTML supports row/colspan since ages...

Comment: Yeah, but ExtJS Grid is much more complex in it's structure so it's not possible to do such a thing. Anyway I never had any scenario with such a need in my four years of ExtJS. There is a row expander if that helps you.

Comment: I have to make a fully new business application from scratch, I have no constraints on the architecture and this gives me freedom but also brings the danger to make mistakes. if I go let's say ASP.NET MVC with ExtJS, would I be able to still include some server controls like an ASP.NET XtraGrid from devexpress with the other ExtJs controls? is that possible?

Comment: Uhh, I can tell you that for sure but you might have a closer look at [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net/) I am using a custom approach therefore I have no experience with that. But as far as I now both system that should be possible!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is kind of late, but it is a solution, it was created by a Sencha developer:
[Row Spanning Solution](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?103133-GridPanel-row-spanning-%28well-sort-of...%29).

And he also gives some suggestion [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109728-Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-Merge-cells-on-different-rows).